# i have a exception when deleting entity framework object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

i don't know what is wrong exactly or what is i should do to delete the object correctly without exception so this the function that i have problem with :

```
protected void RemoveAddDrugSurg()
{
    Surgery sur;
    DrugsList drug;
    Surgery surObject;
    DrugsList drugObject;
    try
    {
        if (Session["OldSurgs"] != null)
        {
            var SurgList = Session["OldSurgs"] as List<Surgery>;
            if (SurgList.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (ListItem li in chlSurg.Items)
                {
                    surObject = null;
                    Int64 index = Convert.ToInt64(li.Value);
                    surObject = SurgList.Find(s => s.SurgeryID == index);
                    if (surObject == null && li.Selected)
                    {
                        sur = new Surgery();
                        sur.VisitID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["VID"]);
                        sur.SurgeryID = Convert.ToInt32(li.Value);
                        Diabetes.AddToSurgeries(sur);
                    }
                    else if (surObject != null && !li.Selected)
                    {

                        Diabetes.CreateObjectSet<Surgery>().Attach(surObject);
                        Diabetes.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(surObject, EntityState.Deleted);
                    }
                }
                Diabetes.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        if (Session["OldDrugs"] != null)
        {
            var DrugList = Session["OldDrugs"] as List<DrugsList>;
            if (DrugList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (ListItem li in chlDrugs.Items)
                {
                    drugObject = null;
                    Int64 index = Convert.ToInt64(li.Value);
                    drugObject = DrugList.Find(d => d.DrugID == index);
                    if (drugObject == null && li.Selected)
                    {
                        drug = new DrugsList();
                        drug.VisitID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["VID"]);
                        drug.DrugID = Convert.ToInt32(li.Value);
                        Diabetes.AddToDrugsLists(drug);
                    }
                    else if (drugObject != null && !li.Selected)
                    {
                        Diabetes.CreateObjectSet<DrugsList>().Attach(drugObject);
                        Diabetes.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(drugObject, EntityState.Deleted);
                    }
                }
                Diabetes.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

and the exception appeared is:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check your app.config?

Comment: for what ?i used the same way to delete other object and it worked well but now i don't know what to do!!!!

Comment: And on what line is the exception thrown? If its on the .Attach() line then you cached surObject is still/already tracked

Comment: I usually use DeleteObject(obj) to delete

Comment: i tried it and i got exception i don't know what is wrong!!!

Comment: On which line is the exception being thrown?

Comment: this the exception when i used DeleteObject(obj) : The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

Comment: this line :   Diabetes.CreateObjectSet<Surgery>().Attach(surObject);

Comment: Your entity is already|still attached. So the problem is not in this code but in how it is called and how you manage the lifetime of the context.

Comment: so how to solve that please because i am new with this approach

Comment: finally i got i used "using" for each scope to avoid interruption between sessions thanks a lot all for help :)

Comment: Write this result as answer please and accept your own answer, so that everyone can see that the problem is solved.

Comment: sure but i can't now i have to wait because of"Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 4 hours."

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not show where **surObject** came from. My guess is that you are trying to Attach surObject to a new ObjectContext. If 'Diabetis' ObjectContext: you might be creating it in on  HTTP request, and the surObject (from session)is from previous request. An EntityObject can only be attached to one ObjectCOntext at the time. If you want to transfer it to another ObjectContext, you need to detach it first.

To delte an object you should call **ObjectContext.DelteObject**, This should also remove it from parent collection.

Comment: You did not tell us what "doesn't work" means.  As described above, you probably have problems with ObjectContext live time management. There are usually two approaches: one ObjectContext instance per request or one ObjectContext instance per session. You should never use one object context per application.

Comment: i said in comments above that there was a problem with the sessions because i was using the same context object over all the page so to avoid that i used "using" for every scope and this was the only way that i found to make things work :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, I used the keyword "using" for each scope to avoid interruption between sessions.

Thank you all for the help :)